# Replacing X-Frame-Options with CSP

Tags: content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am migrating from X-Frame-Options to Content Security Policy to fix the click-jacking vulnerability. My application used to set the `SAMEORIGIN` policy in hte `X-Frame-Options` header. What is the equivalent option in `Content-Security-Policy`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)

- `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` ➡ `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'`
- `X-Frame-Options: DENY` ➡ `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'`

See also https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options